# How can I implement infinitive data structure for obtaining items on demand in F#

Tags: f#

I need to name nodes in a graph with following letters of alphabet.
When I am creating a new node (on-demand) I just need to pick up a first unused letter from the set of chars.

What is the best way to implement such a structure/computation in F#?. 
Note that the following letters should be pick up on-demand.

Let assume that I have infinitive collection of letters like this (this is repeating collection of chars but lets neglect it) :

```
let alphabet = 
            Seq.initInfinite (fun index -> 
                    let alphabet' = "abcdefghijklmnoperstuvxwz"
                    alphabet'.Chars(index % alphabet'.Length)
                )
```

I am particularly interested to have following semantic:

alphabet.next() // produces 'a'
... some time ...
alphabet.next() // produces 'b'
... some time ...
alphabet.next() // produces 'c' 
and so on

I have been considering sequences, lazy lists and asynchronous sequences but from my best knowledge it does not meet my needs. I do not want also use complex libraries like Rx etc

I suspect it can be nicely done with lazy function, state monads or something similar but have no clue how to connect the pieces together in a functional way

Answer (score 3):

Sequences can reference themselves, so how about this?

```
let alphabet = 
    let alphabet' = "abcdefghijklmnoperstuvxwz" 
    let rec loop() = seq {
        yield! alphabet' 
        yield! loop()
        }
    loop()

alphabet |> Seq.take 100 |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 2):

actually your `alphabet` sequence comes pretty close if but if you need to *pull* continuously outside something like a *foreach* it might have to much overhead attached.

so what about

```
let pullNext =                                
   let cs = "abcdefghijklmnoperstuvxwz"        
   let i = ref 0
   fun () ->
      let c = cs.[!i]
      i := (!i + 1) % cs.Length
      c
```

this will give you (what I think) you want:

```
> pullNext ();;
val it : char = 'a'
> pullNext();;
val it : char = 'b'
> pullNext();;
val it : char = 'c'
```

of course this is not pure (and does not use much monadic magic) nor is it very *functional* but alas your `alphabet.next()` can never be a *pure* **function** anyways ;)

### caution

this is **not** thread-safe so use locks inside the inner function if you need this

Comment: I like it! As I am using f# 4.0 I can even omit 'ref' calls. Maybe it is not pure but at least it is clear